# Extract some rows in the matrix at fixed intervals?

Tags: r, matrix

How to extract two rows every three rows of the following matrix?

```
simple <- matrix(1:300,nrow=50,ncol=4)
```

Comment: Equivalently dropping every 3rd row?

Comment: the generalisable solution is to combine as many `seq` statements as you need, optionally adding `sort` if you want to retain the order - like `my_seq <- sort(c(seq(1,50,3), seq(2,50,3)))`, and use this as the row index `simple[my_seq, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another similar option

2 every 3

```
k=2
skp=3

unlist(sapply(seq(1,nrow(simple),k+skp),function(x){x:(x+k-1)},simplify=F))
[1]  1  2  6  7 11 12 16 17 21 22 26 27 31 32 36 37 41 42 46 47
```

7 every 3

```
k=7
skp=3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem was solved using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: generate a certain sequence

Generate the sequence you want to subset the rows like this:

```
rows <- sort(c(seq(1,nrow(simple), 5), seq(2,nrow(simple), 5)))
simple[rows,]
```

Output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1   51  101  151
 [2,]    2   52  102  152
 [3,]    6   56  106  156
 [4,]    7   57  107  157
 [5,]   11   61  111  161
 [6,]   12   62  112  162
 [7,]   16   66  116  166
 [8,]   17   67  117  167
 [9,]   21   71  121  171
[10,]   22   72  122  172
[11,]   26   76  126  176
[12,]   27   77  127  177
[13,]   31   81  131  181
[14,]   32   82  132  182
[15,]   36   86  136  186
[16,]   37   87  137  187
[17,]   41   91  141  191
[18,]   42   92  142  192
[19,]   46   96  146  196
[20,]   47   97  147  197
```

Maybe you want this:

```
simple[seq_len(nrow(simple)) %% 3 != 0,]
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1   51  101  151
 [2,]    2   52  102  152
 [3,]    4   54  104  154
 [4,]    5   55  105  155
 [5,]    7   57  107  157
 [6,]    8   58  108  158
 [7,]   10   60  110  160
 [8,]   11   61  111  161
 [9,]   13   63  113  163
[10,]   14   64  114  164
[11,]   16   66  116  166
[12,]   17   67  117  167
[13,]   19   69  119  169
[14,]   20   70  120  170
[15,]   22   72  122  172
[16,]   23   73  123  173
[17,]   25   75  125  175
[18,]   26   76  126  176
[19,]   28   78  128  178
[20,]   29   79  129  179
[21,]   31   81  131  181
[22,]   32   82  132  182
[23,]   34   84  134  184
[24,]   35   85  135  185
[25,]   37   87  137  187
[26,]   38   88  138  188
[27,]   40   90  140  190
[28,]   41   91  141  191
[29,]   43   93  143  193
[30,]   44   94  144  194
[31,]   46   96  146  196
[32,]   47   97  147  197
[33,]   49   99  149  199
[34,]   50  100  150  200
```

Comment: I don't want to cull lines that are multiples of 3, but want to extract three lines every two lines. For example, the first time I extract lines 1 and 2, the second time I need to extract lines 6 and 7, and so on. Eventually, the extracted matrix should be 20*4.

Comment: @liguancghen, Check edited answer!

Comment: Many thanks! The next question is, how to extract 7 rows every 3 rows? For example， the first time to extract lines 1 to 7, the second time to extract lines 11 to 17, and so on. Finally, a 35*4 matrix is obtained. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @liguancghen, Then use `rows <- sort(c(seq(1,nrow(simple), 10), seq(2,nrow(simple), 10), seq(3,nrow(simple), 10), seq(4,nrow(simple), 10), seq(5,nrow(simple), 10), seq(6,nrow(simple), 10), seq(7,nrow(simple), 10)))` instead. You can change the sequence to whatever you want.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. Next, what if you extract 20 rows? Is there an easier way? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @liguancghen, what do you mean with 20 rows? The first 20 rows?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The second answerer has solved my problem.